# How to save QGIS composer template with image - e.g. company logo?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, jpg, template

I can't figure out how to save QGIS Print composer template with image. In our map compositions we always have company logo in one place. It is easy to add image (logo) to composer and place it to spot I need. But when I save template, it saves without image (logo). Is there some setting for it? Am I misssing something or there is no way so far to save template including image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. When I saved template I did it to different folder than project was saved  in. The image was specified through relative path but from project - not template itself. All I had to do was **specify image through absolute path**. Now the template shows the image.

(In the *Project / Project properties... Ctrl+Shift+P* under *General tab / Save paths: absolute*. Open the template and in *Item properties / Image source* check if the path is absolute path leading to the proper folder. If it is done you must save / overwrite the template. After that you can load templates to any projects in any folder and it will link the image properly as far as the absolute path will be accessible.)

Answer (score 2):

I came across this and I'm not sure in which version it was introduced, but from 3.16 there is the possibility to specifically embed a file from the image selector dropdown in the layout context. Just make sure you use Save As Template or it won't be saved.

[image: How To Embed Images in QGIS Map Layout]