# How to import PDF or SVG image?

Tags: qgis, import, pdf, svg

I am using QGIS 3.28 and I am brand new to this! I am simply trying to create a template with our company logo.  I have created the logo in CorelDraw and AI and saved as a PDF and a SVG. I just need to IMPORT it into QGIS so that I can use it for the creation of templates.

I have spent too many hours reading the manual and the community forum and still can't figure this out - and I imagine it is incredibly easy once I learn how.

Comment: Have you tired the answer in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90612/how-to-save-qgis-composer-template-with-image-e-g-company-logo?rq=1 Logos are added in the print composer using "Add Image".

Comment: Thank you, I will try the suggestions in that link.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some basic instructions:
[image]